# Conventional Commits type for merge conflicts

Tags: git, conventional-commits

According to the docs https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/ or to another extendable source if I have a merge conflict what a commit type should I use?

Comment: Merge conflicts shouldn't be committed — they should be resolved and then the fixed files should be committed.

Comment: @phd do you have any tutorial how to do it in best way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+resolve+conflicts

Comment: @phd I think you missed the point. The question is what Type do you use when committing the fixed files?
Closest I can see is 'refactor'

Comment: @HuwPendry Merge conflicts must not be committed. The conflict must be resolved and then committed. So no type at all.

Comment: You keep typing the words "and then committed" and yet denying that any committing is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find all the sources that I had read on that topic, but it seems many Conventional Commit users do not use merge commits, and instead rebase their branch to fix conflicts before merging with `--ff-only`.

See [Commit type according to convensional commit when resolving conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75156408/commit-type-according-to-convensional-commit-when-resolving-conflicts)

I believe the approach would be that for each conflict, you would need to figure out to which of your commits the fix would belong. For example, if you have a commit that refactored some code and someone fixed a bug in the same area, you would squash that conflict fix into the `refactor` commit. The idea is to make the history look linear as if your branch introduces changes on top of the previous one, not parallelly.

The idea would be as follows:

1. Make sure that your branches are up-to-date.
2. Attempt rebasing against the branch you're merging: `git checkout <my-branch>`, then `git rebase main` (if merging into main)
3. If there are conflicts, `git rebase` will stop at any commit that causes the conflict. After fixing the conflicts, you can either directly amend the current commit (if it is the one that makes the most sense to add changes to) via `git commit --amend`, or create new commits that you can link to existing ones with `git commit --fixup <commit-hash>`. These commits can later be squashed into the one it has been linked to. Then, `git rebase --continue`.
4. *(optional)* When the rebase is complete, if you have any fixup commits, perform another rebase to squash any fixup commits with `git rebase -i --autosquash main`. This squashes the fixup commits into their “linked” ones.
5. Finally, merge your branch: `git checkout main` and `git merge --ff-only <my-branch>`. The option means it will only merge if it can do so by fast-forwarding (just moving the branch tip to that commit without conflicts), which it should as your rebase took care of recreating the commits on top with conflicts handled.

Comment: That's all very well, but if you've pushed your branch and started a PR into main, but someone completes their PR before you, after rebasing locally you would have to force push your changes to overwrite history on the server which is at least frowned on, and may even be prevented by policy.  The point is you can't always avoid merge commits, so in that situation what comment would you use on the merge commit?

Comment: You wouldn't force push, but rebase again. It isn't described in the convention, because maintainers that wrote it [use and suggest using rebases instead of merges](https://github.com/conventional-commits/conventionalcommits.org/issues/454#issuecomment-1136024464).

So if you have to use conventional commits and merge commits, you would write your own convention to add a type (which they suggest doing on their specification) for merge commits, or in which merge commits would belong.